# Can't initialize mysql after changing data and logs directory

Tags: mysql

I stopped mysql service to change the data and logs directory. I've created the new directories, gave them mysql ownership, edited the my.cnf this way:

```
datadir=/mysql-dados
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/mysql-logs/error.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

/mysql-dados and mysql-logs is intended to be the new directories.

Finally I moved the files from the previous data directory to the new one.

**When I tried to initialize mysql I receive the following error:**

```
mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-04-15 00:19:32 -03; 9s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 13507 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 13478 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13507 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server shutdown complete"

Apr 15 00:19:31 jeditemple-201.hti.local systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Apr 15 00:19:32 jeditemple-201.hti.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 15 00:19:32 jeditemple-201.hti.local systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Apr 15 00:19:32 jeditemple-201.hti.local systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Apr 15 00:19:32 jeditemple-201.hti.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

**In the error.log I found this:**

--initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
The designated data directory /mysql-dados/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

What's the problem here? I'd be glad for any suggestions you give me.

Comment: Forgive me but I'm not familiar with DadOS , is it an API or function you send parameters and it makes bad jokes for you?

Comment: But all jokes aside, it could be something with that dados .. maybe it too has settings, and when you changed the actual physicial location, maybe there is a config file or even table that dados uses on top of mysql perhaps?

Comment: /mysql-dados is the name I set for the new directory. Dados means data in my first language (Portuguese).

Comment: Thank you for that, I was curious.   Looking at the error message is says the directory is unusable .. that is disturbing.   Well even though logistically it seems you can just move a few files and change a few things, there might be records in the database that tell it where it was originally, and so perhaps it fails to load due to that.  I wonder, can you get a blank MySQL server going in that directory with a dummy table?    Just a basic boot with empty config to verify it can at least launch properly from that location, then you can work backwards through each thing until you find it.

Comment: I don't know if I got your point, but I think the server will always read from the my.cnf file which has the current position. The default location for mysql data is /var/lib/mysql, so I don't know if I could install mysql server in that new location.

Comment: Well, when you face unknown problems, you must start at each step.  And the first one is, can we get MySQL to run again?  And if so, can we then get it to run from the new location?  And then penultimatley , can we get it to run from the new location WITH all the old data.

Comment: If you find you can't get it to work at all in the new location, its obviously something to do with that.  But if you can get it to work there with a new install, then its maybe a config settings thats in a table that when you changed the directory you broke the link to where it was pointing or something like that.  So, try to get it to work from a blank database, then try the new location with the blank database, THEN try to import the data sort of thing, work each step until you can find WHAT is causing the issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your support. I don't have problems with losing that data though, cause It's a new instance, the database files inside the new directory are default from mysql, like performance_schema and sys. Do you think It's worth trying to remove everything inside the directory before initializing the service?